# Discord js, node js, using discord id for creating new_key name

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Im trying to have a word counter but not have to manually add the users myself by using the messages.author.id as the new_key name. But it is not detecting if it already exists as a key. (I already have a total server word counter, but not a user word counter).

```
//~~MAIN.JS~~

 if(!(People[message.author.id])){
            People.push({[message.author.id]: 1});
            var writestring2 = JSON.stringify(People);
            fs.writeFileSync("data/people.json", writestring2);
            console.log('success');
            console.log(message.author.id);
        }
        else{
            console.log('fail');
            console.log(message.author.id);


//~~PEOPLE.JSON~~

[{}]
```

Comment: So, is `People` an array of objects initially, like `[{}]`? It should be an empty object, like `{}`.

Comment: It is like [{}], im pretty sure i did it like that because it wouldnt let me push it into the json

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding where to use arrays and objects. Currently `People` is an array of objects. For example:

```js
const People = [];

People.push({ foo: 'bar' });
People.push({ one: 'two' });
People.push({ hello: 'world' });

console.log(People);

// This is an array, so you'd search by index.
People[0]; // { foo: 'bar' }
People[1]; // { one: 'two' }
People[2]; // { hello: 'world' }

// Not by property key.
People['foo']; // undefined
People['one']; // undefined
People['hello']; // undefined
```

Since you want to search by a key and not an index, you should use an object, not an array. So, instead of pushing new objects, you'd just assign properties with brackets.

```js
const People = {};

People['123456'] = 1;
People['098765'] = 0;

console.log(People);
```

In your code, that would look like this:

```js
if (!People[message.author.id]) {
  // THIS LINE IS CHANGING
  People[message.author.id] = 1;
  var writestring2 = JSON.stringify(People);
  fs.writeFileSync("data/people.json", writestring2);
  console.log("success");
  console.log(message.author.id);
} else {
  console.log("fail");
  console.log(message.author.id);
}
```

You'll also have to change `people.json` to `{}` (an object, not an array). As a tip, it's often recommended to avoid [negated conditions](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-negated-condition), although this doesn't affect the functionality of your code.